# LSTM Model Not Learning When Labels Are Encoded

Tags: classification, lstm, one-hot-encoding

I'm doing classification using LSTM. Currently having two labels.
My model was working great until I changed the labeling from int to one hot encoder.

Old code (working):

```
if i%2 == 0 :
   targets=targets.append({'seq_id':counter,'val':1},ignore_index=True)
else :
   targets=targets.append({'seq_id':counter,'val':-1},ignore_index=True) 

...

model.add(LSTM(int(num_features*4),input_shape=(num_rows,num_cols),  return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(int(num_features*4),   dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

New Code (not working - stuck at val_acc=0.5)

```
if i%2 == 0 :
   targets=targets.append({'seq_id':counter,'val':'bic'},ignore_index=True)
else :
   targets=targets.append({'seq_id':counter,'val':'reno'},ignore_index=True)
...

targets = targets.values[:,1]
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(targets)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(targets)
targets = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

...

model.add(LSTM(int(num_features*4),input_shape=(num_rows,num_cols),  return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(int(num_features*4),   dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')) #That line Changed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing one-hot encoding, then you should change the activation of the last Dense layer to softmax.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the loss function to categorical_crossentropy, it worked.